# Iterating custom parameters for Schlib library component in vbs

Tags: altium

I have problem iterating through custom parameters for a component in Schlib library.
I use SchLibIterator_Create method to get components.
And I can get next component with Set LibComp = LibraryIterator.FirstSchObject
I can read and set Comment, Description...
But when I want to create iterator on the chosen component (to get parameters), it fails with a message "altium object doesn't support this property or method".
I read about it, and actually examined few examples found on script repositories, and everything in my code looks the same, only that it doesn't work.

````
        Workspace = GetWorkspace
        Project  = Workspace.DM_FocusedProject
        If Project Is Nothing Then
            ShowError "Err1"
        End If

        ' Obtain the schematic server interface.
        If SchServer Is Nothing Then
            ShowError "Err2"
        End If

        Set CurrentSheet = SchServer.GetCurrentSchDocument
        If CurrentSheet Is Nothing Then
            ShowError "Err3"
        End If


        DocType = GetWorkspace.DM_FocusedDocument.DM_DocumentKind
        If DocType = "SCHLIB" Then
        ShowMessage ("Library opened")
        end if

        prtName = "ALFG2PF12"
        AddSCH = AddSchLib(prtName)
        If AddSCH Then
           ShowMessage ("comp found")
        else
            ShowMessage ("comp not found")
        end if


        Function AddSchLib(component)
            Dim CurrentLib
            Dim LibraryIterator
            Dim LibComp
            Dim ChildIterator
            Dim Parameter
            Dim EntriesNames
            Dim LibCompNameNext
            Dim LibCompNamePrev

            Set CurrentLib = SCHServer.GetCurrentSchDocument
            If CurrentLib Is Nothing Then Exit Function

            Set LibraryIterator = CurrentLib.SchLibIterator_Create
            If Not (LibraryIterator Is Nothing) Then ShowMessage("LibraryIterator not nothing")
            If (LibraryIterator Is Nothing) Then ShowMessage("LibraryIterator is nothing")

            LibraryIterator.AddFilter_ObjectSet(MkSet(eSchComponent))

            Set LibComp = LibraryIterator.FirstSchObject

            LibCompNameNext = LibComp.LibReference


            Do
               LibCompNamePrev = LibCompNameNext
               If LibCompNameNext = component Then
                  AddSchLib = true
                  
                  ShowMessage (LibComp.LibReference + " / " + LibComp.Designator.Text + " / " + LibComp.Comment.Text )    
                  
                  'parameters
                  
                  ChildIterator = LibComp.SchIterator_Create   ' HERE, ERROR IS THROWN
                 
                  ChildIterator.AddFilter_ObjectSet(MkSet(eParameter))        
                  
                  Parameter = ChildIterator.FirstSchObject                
                  
                  While Not (Parameter Is Nothing)
                   EntriesNames = Parameter.Name + " " + EntriesNames
                   Set Param = ChildIterator.NextSchObject
                  Wend
                  LibComp.SchIterator_Destroy(ChildIterator)
                  ShowMessage("Parametri: " + Parameter.Text)
                  EntriesNames = ""
                  ShowMessage ("param: " + Parameter.Name)
                  Exit Function
                  
                  
               End If
               Set LibComp = LibraryIterator.NextSchObject
               LibCompNameNext = LibComp.LibReference
               ShowMessage (LibCompNameNext)
            Loop Until LibCompNameNext = LibCompNamePrev
            CurrentLib.SchLibIterator_Destroy(LibraryIterator)
            AddSchLib = false
        End Function





```
````

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: Registered at Altium, but their forum is unavailable, as their ticket support is dead, for a long time now. That's why I ask here. 
If you're interested, search rumours on reddit "altium support".

Comment: I just logged in to the Altium forum without issue - even though I no longer have an active Altium license.  Questions and answers still seem active.  If I were you, I'd want to switch to KiCad.  Costs much less greenbacks, the files are open, and you can script using python.  Version 8 is very good.  Never been happier since Protel.  https://forum.live.altium.com/#/forums/245  https://www.kicad.org/

Comment: Thanks for info about Kicad. My organization decides about tools, not me. 
And, still I receive "Sorry, Altium forum not available. ". I tryed Chrome and FF, and cleared cache. But your info, to know that for somebody this forum works, will help me because I can test later through other network !!! Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried with FF as well as Edge on the Altium forum.  Both worked from here (Vermont, USA).

Comment: Hey, works with another account - my old, not used for years...!

Comment: But, I solved a problem. Missing Set keyword !!
Set Parameter = ChildIterator.FirstSchObject